# Eigen Dynamic-sized matrix verticaly/horizontaly Linspaced?

Tags: eigen, linspace

I'm currently working on a project where i need to be able to create matrix such as :

```
MatrixXi lin_spaced_horizontaly = 

0 1 2 3 4 ... ncols
0 1 2 3 4 ... ncols
0 1 2 3 4 ... ncols

MatrixXi lin_spaced_verticaly =
0 0 0 
1 1 1 
2 2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4
 . . . 
nrows nrows nrows
```

Currently i am trying things like that :

```
Eigen::VectorXi v_lin_vec = Eigen::VectorXi::LinSpaced(nrows_, 0, nrows_).transpose
Eigen::MatrixXi v_lin_matrix (nrows_, ncols_);
for (auto i = 0; i<ncols_; i++)
        v_lin_matrix << v_lin_vec;

Eigen::VectorXi h_lin_vec = Eigen::VectorXi::LinSpaced(ncols_, 0, ncols_)
Eigen::MatrixXi h_lin_matrix (nrows_, ncols_);
for (auto i = 0; i<ncols_; i++)
        h_lin_matrix << h_lin_vec;
```

And I am getting results such as :

```
v_lin_matrix 
-------------
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0

h_lin_matrix
-------------
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `.rowwise().replicate(ncols_)` and `.colwise().replicate(nrows_)` like so:

```
Eigen::MatrixXi v_lin_matrix = Eigen::VectorXi::LinSpaced(nrows_, 0, nrows_)
                                     .rowwise().replicate(ncols_);
Eigen::MatrixXi h_lin_matrix = Eigen::RowVectorXi::LinSpaced(ncols_, 0, ncols_)
                                     .colwise().replicate(nrows_);
```

Or alternatively:

```
Eigen::MatrixXi v_lin_matrix = Eigen::VectorXi::LinSpaced(nrows_, 0, nrows_)
                                     .replicate(1,ncols_);
Eigen::MatrixXi h_lin_matrix = Eigen::RowVectorXi::LinSpaced(ncols_, 0, ncols_)
                                     .replicate(nrows_,1);
```

Regarding your use of `<<`: This is meant to be used in combination with the `,` operator to initialize a matrix in a single expression, like this:

```
 Eigen::MatrixXi A(4,ncols_);
 A << row0, row1, row2, row3;
```

What you wrote will assert at runtime (if you compile without `-DNDEBUG`, which I strongly recommend until your code is sufficiently tested!)

Comment: If this solved your problem, you can accept this answer (no need to write "thank you" comments)